# clearing and seeding database from endpoint in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, seeding

++updated with screen shot of server error++

I'm trying to set up a rest API that can be cleared and then have the data in my postgres db re-seeded via an endpoint.  I'm doing this with Django with json data in a fixtures file, executing a series of functions in my views. This has worked great so far, but now I'm trying to add data with foreign key fields.

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 4000)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**in views.py**

```
def seed(request):
    Profile.objects.all().delete()
    reset(Profile)
    for profile in all_profiles:
        add_profile(profile)
    Post.objects.all().delete()
    reset(Post)
    for post in all_posts:
        add_post(post)
    Comment.objects.all().delete()
    reset(Comment)
    for comment in all_comments:
        add_comment(comment)
    return HttpResponse('database cleared and seeded')

def add_profile(new_profile):
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.create(**new_profile)
    profile_instance.save()

def add_post(new_post):
    post_instance = Post.objects.create(**new_post)
    post_instance.save()

def add_comment(new_comment):
    comment_instance = Comment.objects.create(**new_comment)
    comment_instance.save()

def reset(table):
    sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), [table])
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for sql in sequence_sql:
            cursor.execute(sql)
```

**some example seed objects:**

```
all_profiles = [
  {
    "name": "Robert Fitzgerald Diggs",
    "profile_name": "RZA",
    "email": "abbotofthewu@wutang.com"
  }
]

all_posts = [
  {
    "title": "Bring da Ruckus",
    "body": "some text",
    "profile": 5
  }
]

all_comments = [
  {
    "title": "famous dart",
    "body": "Ghostface catch the blast of a hype verse My Glock burst",
    "profile": 6,
    "post": 1
  }
]
```

Now when I hit my endpoint I get an error like "ValueError: Cannot assign "5": "Post.profile" must be a "Profile" instance."  I assume this means that the integer "5" in this case is just a number and not viewed as a reference to anything, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I thought creating the model instance would take care of this.

**Here is my error from the CLI:**
[screenshot of server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bnFO.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

got it figured.  creating an object from the model simply saves the foreign key reference as an integer, but the database needs a full instance, so I had to query the database for the foreign object in question, variable-ize it and write over the integer with the variable before saving.

**new functions from views:**

```
def add_profile(new_profile):
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.create(**new_profile)
    profile_instance.save()

def add_post(new_post):
    found_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=new_post['profile'])
    new_post['profile'] = found_profile
    post_instance = Post.objects.create(**new_post)
    post_instance.save()

def add_comment(new_comment):
    found_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=new_comment['profile'])
    found_post = Post.objects.get(id=new_comment['post'])
    new_comment['profile'] = found_profile
    new_comment['post'] = found_post
    comment_instance = Comment.objects.create(**new_comment)
    comment_instance.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try loading a string instead of an integer?  As in "6" instead of 6?